# Properties of $A-$modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, modules

Let $A$ a ring and $M,N$ two $A-$modules. Let $\varphi:M\longrightarrow N$ a $A-$modules homomorphism.

1) Show that $\ker \varphi$ and $Im(\varphi)$ are respectively submodules of $M$ and $N$.

2) Show that $M/\ker\varphi\cong Im(\varphi)$.

Modules are very new to me, so if you can check if my proofs are correct it would be great.

What I did:

1) The fact that $\ker \varphi$ is a subgroup of $M$ is obvious. Now if $a\in A$ and $x\in \ker\varphi$, then $\varphi(ax)=a\varphi(x)=0$ and thus $ax\in \ker \varphi$. Therefore, it's a submodule. FThe fact that $Im(\varphi)$ is a subgroup of $N$ is obvious. Now let $x\in Im(\varphi)$ and $a\in A$. There is $y\in M$ s.t. $x=\varphi(y)$. Therefore, $$ax=a\varphi(y)=\varphi(ay).$$
Since $M$ is a module, $ay\in M$ and thus $ax\in Im(\varphi)$. Therefore $Im(\varphi)$ is a submodule of $N$.

Is it correct ?

2) I defined $\tau: M/\ker\varphi\to Im(\varphi)$ by $$\tau(m+\ker \varphi)=\varphi(m).$$

**$\tau$ is well defined:** If $m+\ker\varphi=n+\ker\varphi$, then $m=n+t$ for a $t\in \ker\varphi$ and thus $$\tau(m+\ker\varphi)=\varphi(m)=\varphi(n+t)=\varphi(n)+\varphi(t)=\varphi(n)=\tau(n+\ker\varphi).$$

**Injectivity :** $$\tau(m+\ker\varphi)=\ker\varphi\implies \varphi(m)=0\implies m\in \ker\varphi\implies m+\ker\varphi=\ker\varphi,$$
thus we have the injectivity.

**Surjectivity** Let $x\in Im\varphi$. Then, there is $y\in M$ s.t. $$x=\varphi(y)=\tau(y+\ker\varphi)$$
what prove the claim.

Is it correct ?

Comment: Your proof is mainly using definitions. I do not read your proof carefully but basically it's good.

Answer (score 1):

When you show injectivity, the equality $\tau(m+\ker\varphi)=\ker\varphi$ makes no sense. What you should write is simply that if $\tau(m+\ker\varphi)=0$, then 
$$
\varphi(m)=\tau(m+\ker\varphi)=0,
$$
so $m\in\ker\varphi$, i.e. $m+\ker\varphi=\ker\varphi$.

Other than that typo, all your arguments are correct (and standard).